# DSL to web connectivity is often lost

Tags: dsl

I am experiencing a frequent web connectivity problem via a DSL modem.  The problem usually shows up as a `reload later` screen inside of Google Chrome, as illustrated.   My DSL service was fine for the first 2 months, but in the most recent month this problem has been occurring.  I have this problem several times a day.  A few weeks ago, I used to power cycle (off then on) the DSL modem but this usually did not solve the problem.  However, in recent days, the power cycle does seem to fix the problem.

When the problem occurs, the modem lights do not look unusual.  All the lights are green or flashing green.  This problem happens regardless of whether I am using ethernet or WiFi for the last few meters between the DSL modem and the computer.

What is the likely cause?  How can I help the phone company solve this?  Their staff are not very effective at troubleshooting this.

[image: reload in Chrome]

Comment: Did you call your provider to talk with them first?

Comment: Have you pinpointed the problem to be on the modem end? Does connecting with another device work as expected or not?

Comment: Yes, I've had 2 visits from the phone company.  The problem remains.  zmode: I don't know what you mean by connecting with another device.  I have only one DSL modem. I have 2 computers here and when there is no web connectivity neither computer has web connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

When this happen you can try pinging 8.8.8.8 from command line and if it successfully completed then the problem is your default DNS provider (which automatically configured by your ISP [Internet Service Provider] means your phone company).

You can change the default DNS on your Router's web site. Try either Open-DNS or google-DNS

Open DNS IPs are

1. 208.67.222.222
2. 208.67.220.220

Google DNS IPs are

1. 8.8.8.8
2. 8.8.4.4

You can use this [guide](https://store.opendns.com/setup/) to change DNS IP.

Comment: I usually use 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 so I don't think that will help.  However, the next time I have the problem I will try your ping suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is something you changed on your phone line. Maybe you added an answering machine or FAX machine. Maybe you added an alarm system. Maybe you moved a cordless phone base station. But whatever it is, most likely you either didn't move or didn't install an appropriate DSL line filter.

When you have DSL and you don't have a "whole house splitter" at the point of entry, even device connected to your phone line (except the DSL modem) *must* be connected using aproper DSL filter. Otherwise, the DSL line will disconnect intermittently.

It's very easy to forget about things like alarm systems and satellite TV receivers. But if they connect to the phone line, they have to have a filter.

Comment: I haven't added or changed anything physical to account for this, but since this is a condominium, perhaps somebody touched something somewhere in the building.  There is a DSL filter inline.  This being a condo, it's here in the condo unit, not down in the common areas or utility rooms.

Comment: Other than the DSL modem, what's connected to the line? (Make sure you include everything -- alarm systems, TiVo boxes, anything that connects to the phone line.)

Comment: I see a DSL splitter and from there, a phone and a DSL modem.  I presumed, perhaps incorrectly, that the splitter also acts as a filter.  I will inquire with condo staff about anything they know that might be relevant.

Comment: The splitter acts like a filter. You can connect telephones to the phone side of the splitter. If you don't have anything else at all connected to the phone line, you should be okay. (You can probably log into your modem and check the line statistics.)

Comment: Downstream SNR margin is 31 db. Downstream attenuation is 11 db. Downstream throughput is 2.5 Mb/s compared to the promised rate of 3 Mb/s.